# Unable to push due to git status deleted files?

Tags: bash, git, shell, command

**I will be straightforward.**

My professor guided us at pushing our very first text file to the git website. She then gave us an individual activity where we will push another, but should only use git add., git commit -m "text", and git push origin master (that is what she said because that's all we have to use). Whenever I use git status, the image below shows up which probably hinders my ability to push. Any tips on how I can fix this?

[image]

I tried git checkout -- and doing the suggested command which is git restore . When doing both, it just generated another command line, and when we confirmed it using git status, it is still there.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `git status` you get the changes you've made since the last commit, in your case it is telling you that the changes you made are that you deleted the file file `../activities/aboutme.txt`, if you were to modify or delete any other file then that would show up if you run `git status` again.

If you want to keep that file you just need to run `git restore ../activities/aboutme.txt`, if you want to commit that you deleted the file then run `git add ../activities/aboutme.txt` or if you just want to add all the changes you've made run `git add .`, although you would have to move to the root directory, since on the picture it looks like you are not on the root directory of your project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's nothing wrong with git! I suppose you had a file named `aboutme.txt` and you've pushed it to your repository before and now you've deleted that file and that's why `git status` gives you that thing. If you want to restore the deleted file you should run these two commands in order:

```
git reset HEAD
git checkout -- .
```

But if you want to commit the deleted file just use these commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Text file deleted"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you deleted your file by using git rm command and didn't commit it due to that showing on sit status. Please commit it by using git commit command. It will be remove from your tracker

Comment: If `git rm` had been used, the deletion would be staged. An unstaged deletion is evidence that just `rm` was used. Git is noticing that the file is missing from the tree, but the file is still in the index. `git commit` cannot be used (without `--allow-empty`), because the display is showing clearly that there are no staged changes.